EasyMock createMock exception when creating bean
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.lang.Object]: Factory method 'createMock' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 51966
Bean must be created normally

We will need a stacktrace and more details to answer the question

Please provide more context or code to understand the issue with EasyMock and the bean creation.
